# sapply() in R: why returns input?

Tags: r

Why does this code:

```
sapply(c(1, 3, 4, 0), print)
```

Returns:

```
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 0
[1] 1 3 4 0
```

Why it returns the input too?

Comment: I don't understand the closure votes. The question seems entirely clear. And the explanation and comment by @David seem entirely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sapply()` is returning a vector of your printed values but first printing each one as they're called. This may be more clear if you look at this example:

```
> x <- sapply(1:4,print)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
> x
[1] 1 2 3 4
> y <- sapply(1:4,function(x) x)
> y
[1] 1 2 3 4
> identical(x,y)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused how this example works, and I thought I understood the `apply` functions!

Comment: This post may help claify what the apply funtions do: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/2167315 My example is just illustrating that you're seeing the each value printed individually because it is a side effect of the `print()` function.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `print` prints its argument (hence the name), but it also returns them.

```
> x <- print( 1 )
[1] 1
> x
[1] 1
```

We don't see the `[1] 1` usually because `print` returns its argument invisibly.